# Add rows to SQL table based on a list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

So I have a table like this and an attribute list - (`'attr1'`, `'attr2'`, `'attr3'`).

```
id | attr_name | attr_value
----------------------------
 1 |   attr1   |  val1 
 1 |   attr2   |  val2
 1 |   attr3   |  val3 
 2 |   attr1   |  val1
 2 |   attr2   |  val4
```

I want to make a query where this table can be "expanded" to be the following and then make a query using it.

```
id | attr_name | attr_value
----------------------------
 1 |   attr1   |  val1 
 1 |   attr2   |  val2
 1 |   attr3   |  val3 
 2 |   attr1   |  val1
 2 |   attr2   |  val4
 2 |   attr3   |  null
```

The attribute list is given to me and dynamic.

Comment: Do you just want to insert a new record with constant values? Else, please explain the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross join the IDs and the attribute names and then left join the table to get the attribute values or `NULL` if no match was found.

```
SELECT x1.id,
       x2.attr_name,
       t2.attr_value
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.id
                    FROM elbat t1) x1
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('attr1'),
                               ('attr2'),
                               ('attr3')) x2 (attr_name)
            LEFT JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.id = x1.id
                         AND t2.attr_name = x2.attr_name
       ORDER BY x1.id,
                x2.attr_name;
```

Comment: I'm actually using Hibernate and now I'm trying to figure out how to get the "VALUES" table populated as a Hibernate query parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: The hibernate query would look something like: ```"(VALUES :attrList)"``` but a regular string list is not going to work as it's going to quote the entire parenthesized attribute. Hmmmm.....

Comment: @breakingduck: No, sorry no idea about Hibernate. You can search if a question regarding the `VALUES` clause in Hibernate already exists and if not ask a new one. But please don't change this question to be something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
ids AS ( SELECT DISTINCT id
         FROM sourcetable ),
attrs AS ( SELECT DISTINCT attr_name
           FROM sourcetable )
INSERT INTO sourcetable (id, attr_name)
SELECT id, attr_name
FROM ids, attrs
EXCEPT
SELECT id, attr_name
FROM sourcetable
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this seems obvious, but did you try

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
```

?

Then when you query your table it should contain the value

Edit: also you may want to have a unique key

Comment: I don't want to actually insert into the table. I want to do it on the fly while I'm querying. Like with a smart union or something....